# Printing out blank spaces from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    string filename;
    char character;
    int letters[153] = {};

    cout << "Enter text file name: ";
    cin >> filename;    
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    if (! file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file. Check file name. Exiting program." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    while (file.peek() != EOF)
    {
        file >> character;
        if(!file.fail())
        {
            letters[static_cast<int>(character)]++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 153; i++)
    {
        if (letters[i] > 0)
        {
            cout << static_cast<char>(i) << " " << letters[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}

#endif
```

Hi everyone, my current code counts the frequency of each letter from a text file. However, it does not count the number of blank spaces. Is there a simple way to printout the number of blank spaces in a .txt file?

Also, how come when I'm trying to access a vector item, I run into a seg fault?
For example, if I use:

cout << " " + letters[i] << endl;, it displays a segfault. Any ideas?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that the valid positions for your vector are `letters[0]` through `letters[152]`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Except you would just use an array, because using an `unordered_map` to map small integer values to integers is overkill.

Comment: In your for loop you say "i <= 153" whereas you probably want "i < 153". The standard for for-loops is to use "<" in the condition.

Answer (score 2):

By default, iostreams formatted input extraction operations (those using `>>`) skip past all whitespace characters to get to the first non-whitespace character.  Perhaps surprisingly, this includes the extraction operator for `char`.  In order to consider whitespace characters as characters to be processed as usual, you should alter use the [`noskipws` manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/) before processing:

```
file << std::noskipws;
```

Don't forget to set it back on later:

```
file << std::skipws;
```

What if you're one of those crazy people who wants to make a function that leaves this aspect (or in even all aspects) of the stream state *as it was* before it exits?  Naturally, C++ provides a discouragingly ugly way to achieve this:

```
std::ios_base::fmtflags old_fmt = file.flags();
file << std::noskipws;

...  // Do your thang

file.flags(old_fmt);
```

Comment: Were *you* doing this, would you just use an `std::istreambuf_iterator<>` and belay all the formatting setup?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I would just call `istream::get(char&)` in a loop. Every so often I try getting to the bottom of iostreams, but every time I find it to be a frustrating mess, and I never got comfortable enough with `streambuf` and its ilk to bother with them.

Comment: Just curious. It really is made for this, just unformatted suck-straight-out-of-the-streambuf reading. Its definitely worth your time if you ever have any spare to read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only posting this as an alternative way of doing what you're apparently trying. This uses the same lookup table approach you use in your code, but uses an `istreambuf_iterator` for slurping unformatted  (and unfiltered) raw characters out of the stream buffer directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <climits>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it_inf(inf), it_eof;

    unsigned int arr[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {};
    std::for_each(it_inf, it_eof,
         [&arr](char c){ ++arr[static_cast<unsigned int>(c)];});

    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);++i)
    {
        if (std::isprint(i) && arr[i])
            std::cout << static_cast<char>(i) << ':' << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Executing this on the very source code file itself, (i.e. the code above) generates the following:

```
 :124
#:4
&:3
':2
(:13
):13
*:1
+:4
,:4
/:1
0:3
1:2
2:1
::13
;:10
<:19
=:2
>:7
A:2
B:1
C:1
E:2
F:1
H:1
I:3
L:1
R:2
T:2
U:1
X:1
[:8
]:8
_:10
a:27
b:1
c:19
d:13
e:20
f:15
g:6
h:5
i:42
l:6
m:6
n:22
o:10
p:1
r:37
s:20
t:34
u:10
v:2
z:2
{:4
}:4
```

Just a different way to do it, but hopefully it is clear that usually the C++ standard library offers up elegant ways to do what you desire if you dig deep enough to find whats in there. Wishing you good luck.